# Accessing model data from fragments of viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I'm currently writing an app that displays cooking recipes when clicked.

My data is stored in a custom content provider and the information for my recipes is stored in 3-4 tables.

DetailActivity contains a Fragment(Let's call is MasterFragment).

MasterFragment contains a ViewPager which holds 3 fragments that display the  main parts of my model: general info, ingredients and directions. Let's call them GeneralFragment, IngredientFragment and DirectionFragment.

How it stands now, the 3 fragments of the ViewPager all receive the appropriate Uri and each has a loader that loads the data from the content provider and displays it in my UI.

My problem is that having the data loaded into the 3 fragments adds a lot of complexity to my code when it comes to updating the data in the content provider. On top of that, I feel like that doing in this manner may not be the most efficient way of fetching and displaying my data.

One alternative that I thought of was to query all the data in my MasterFragment and to pass it to each individual fragment of the ViewPager through the its adapter. Once again, this is a hassle that requires a lot of overhead and may not be optimal.

I'm thinking that the best way of doing it may be to centralize the model data into the MasterFragment and have the fragments access that data. I'm just not sure how to implement this. I'm leaning towards using a singleton recipe class but I'd rather here your opinion before implementing it.

I'd appreciate any input and I thank you in advance for your time.

tl;dr: Model needs to be accessed by 3 fragments in a viewpager, what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Depends on your data structure. If the data is logically separate (etc. different tables), then the current approach seems reasonable. Otherwise your second suggestion makes sense. Singleton should probably be avoided, as it leaks the data out of it's scope.

Comment: Upon further research, it seems like using singleton is discouraged in android. Would you happen to have any tips or tricks for centralizing the model data in my MasterFragment and having it accessed by the fragments in the ViewPager?

Comment: Your idea on getting references to the Fragments view the `PagerAdapter` seems reasonable. Note that the framework implementations (`FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`) don't expose any method to retrieve the `Fragment` instance based on index, so where I need to get the reference I copy and modify these classes to include such a method myself. For example, in my custom `FragmentPagerAdapter` I have: `public final Fragment getFragment(ViewGroup container, int position) {return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(container.getId(), getItemId(position)));}`